# How to combine two flat lists into one nested object

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have three lists which contains three same properties in each collection. I want to combine a result into one collection. Ex classes structure is as below

```
public class Order
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    // Few other Properties of OrderDetail
}
public class PaymentDetail
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    // Few other Properties form PaymentDetail
}

public class CouponUsageDetail
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    // Few other Properties form CouponUsageDetail
}
```

This type of output is coming from one API service where each class is in form of list object (JSON format) and we need to perform some operations on this. All three properties (ProductId,CustomerId, OrderId) contains same values in each collection which means all three properties are repeated in each collection. We need to perform some look ups on these collections. So in normal way what we can do with it is as - start a foreach from Order list and filter all three matching properties of PaymentDetail and CouponUsageDetail. But it would be costlier in term of performance when the data size is increased. So thought of making nesting structure upfront and avoid lookups. If we make the output nested as below this will help to avoid lookups on PaymentDetail and CouponUsageDetail. 
Ex - we are receiving JOSN in below format

```
{"Orders":[{"ProductId":301,"CustomerId":101,"OrderId":201},{"ProductId":701,"CustomerId":501,"OrderId":601}],"PaymentDetails":[{"ProductId":301,"CustomerId":101,"OrderId":201},{"ProductId":701,"CustomerId":501,"OrderId":601}],"CouponUsageDetails":[{"ProductId":301,"CustomerId":101,"OrderId":201},{"ProductId":701,"CustomerId":501,"OrderId":601}]}
```

and with this output we want to form object as

```
public class OrderDetails
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    // Few other Properties of OrderDetail

    List<PaymentDetail> PaymentDetail { get; set; }
    List<CouponUsageDetail> CouponUsageDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Can you guide, what would be the best optimum usage of linq where we can combine all these three matching properties and make it just one nested structure better?
Thank You!
 **Note**: I know this structure needs to be normalized but please ignore the normalization rule here as this is not in our control.

Comment: Hi @Oxygen. I'm afraid your question is quite unclear. You have explained that you have three classes, which share three properties, and you wish to combine some combination of these, to form a single object, `ResultsCollection`? Now you've shown your models, but not really your scenario: Is it a single instance of each you want to combine? 1000? The expected output from what? What is happening and why are you doing this? What is especially confusing this way in which you have names your classes `CollectionX` yet it seems they are not collections at all, e.g. a `List<T>` or even an `Array`.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood. Sorry for the confusion. Edited the question with scenario and exact problem. Can you please assist?

Comment: @GertArnold Edited the question. Can you please guide?

Comment: @Oxygen, thank you :), a much better question and I'm almost clear except on one point: " where each class is in form of list object"... I assume the API is providing you some JSON or XML? Some block of text that defines the objects? Could you perhaps include an example of what the API provides. I think this may in fact be a serialization issue/question.

Comment: @GeorgeKerwood . Yes its in JSON format. Added a JOSN for your reference

Comment: @GertArnold. As I said please ignore normalization as this structure formation is not in our control. We are receiving the data form API service. Added JSON structure in question about how we are receiving data

Comment: @GertArnold sorry for the confusion. I have created another question. Please have a look if it clears for you. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62114435/how-to-combine-two-list-sharing-same-properties-into-one-nested-object-structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you describing sounds like two standard multi-key LINQ [group joins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-grouped-joins). They are quite efficient (LINQ to Objects implementation uses prepared fast hash based lookups), so no further optimizations are needed:

```
var orderDetails = (
    from o in data.Orders
    join p in data.PaymentDetails
        on new { o.ProductId, o.CustomerId, o.OrderId }
        equals new { p.ProductId, p.CustomerId, p.OrderId }
        into orderPaymentDetails
    join c in data.CouponUsageDetails
        on new { o.ProductId, o.CustomerId, o.OrderId }
        equals new { c.ProductId, c.CustomerId, c.OrderId }
        into orderCouponUsageDetails
    select new OrderDetails
    {
        ProductId = o.ProductId,
        CustomerId = o.CustomerId,
        OrderId = o.OrderId,
        // Few other Properties of OrderDetail
        PaymentDetail = orderPaymentDetails.ToList(),
        CouponUsageDetail = orderCouponUsageDetails.ToList(),
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a number of questions here combined, I'll try to work through them:

### Data Models and Deserialization

With respect to generating a single structure from your API response, I would recommend using the Newtonsoft.Json libraries, available on NuGet [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). They will allow you to deserialize the response from your API, into a single object, which given the sample you provided, should contain a collection of each of your models, `Order`, `PaymentDetail`, `CouponUsageDetail`:

```
public class APIResponceContainer
{
    [JsonProperty("Orders")]
    public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("PaymentDetails")]
    public List<PaymentDetail> PaymentDetails { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("CouponUsageDetails")]
    public List<CouponUsageDetail> CouponUsageDetails { get; set; }

    public APIResponceContainer()
    {
        Orders = new List<Order>();
        PaymentDetails = new List<PaymentDetail>();
        CouponUsageDetails = new List<CouponUsageDetail>();
    }
}
```

Be aware to add the required attributes to each of your models as so:

```
public class Order
{
    [JsonProperty("ProductId")]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("CustomerId")]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("OrderId")]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization then happens from your JSON string, as such:

```
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(myJSONString);
JsonSerializer js = JsonSerializer.Create();
APIResponceContainer APIResponce = (APIResponceContainer)js.Deserialize(stringReader, typeof(APIResponceContainer));
```

### Queries

As discussed in the comments, your data is unfortunately in terrible need of normalization. However, what I have inferred is that you would like to produce a flat structure, maintaining the "Few other Properties" and "key properties", for a combination of `Order`, `PaymentDetail` and `CouponUsageDetail`. You can use `Linq` for this, importantly I would recommend you choose yourself a "Primary Key". In other words, one property that can independently tie all the others together. In the example below, I have choose `OrderID` since it should be unique (?):

```
var flatSequence =
            from order in APIResponce.Orders
            join coupon in APIResponce.CouponUsageDetails on order.OrderId equals coupon.OrderId
            join payment in APIResponce.PaymentDetails on order.OrderId equals payment.OrderId
            select new
            {
                // Here extract all the properties you care about
                OrderID = order.OrderId,
                Customer = order.CustomerId,
                Product = order.ProductId,
                // All the "other Properties" ?
                BankDetail = payment.PaymentOnlyProperty
            };
```

Here I have extracted to `var`, however if you know the final flat structure you would like, of course determine a class of your own to receive the result.

Please comment if there is any questions.

Comment: Thank you for the lead George. The linq structure which you explained similar what I thought initially. This will again create a flat structure. Consider where one oder has multiple couponusages in this case we need to nest couponusages into order object i.e. one order will have list of couponusage. Can you give a hint about how can we achieve this?

Comment: I'd recommend that perhaps, for each model, you have for example a `JSONOrder` class and an `Order` class. In the case of `Coupon` and `Customer` this would then allow `Order` to potentially contain a collection of both without duplicating data inside. You would deserialize to the JSON versions, then use them in a constructor to create the "normal" versions. As for an 1Order` having multiple `Coupons`, you'll need to have a look at linqs `where` and `group by`.

Comment: Perhaps once you have a JSON example of this scenario and your models ready etc, ask a new question. Feel free to ping me here and I'll take a look. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have solution, but i am not sure if it's ok for you. It depends on data format that you have on the begining.

solution:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var collection1 = new Collection1() { PropId1 = 1, PropId2 = 2, PropId3 = 3 };

        var list2 = new List<Collection2>()
        {
            new Collection2
            {
                PropId1 = 11,
                PropId2 = 22,
                PropId3 = 33
            },
            new Collection2
            {
                PropId1 = 22,
                PropId2 = 33,
                PropId3 = 44
            }
        };
        var list3 = new List<Collection3>()
        {
            new Collection3
            {
                PropId1 = 111,
                PropId2 = 222,
                PropId3 = 333
            },
            new Collection3
            {
                PropId1 = 222,
                PropId2 = 333,
                PropId3 = 444
            }
        };

        var result = new ResultCollection(collection1, list2, list3);
        //or
        var result2 = new ResultCollection(collection1) //but in this case you have to change your constructor
        {
            Collection2s = list2,
            Collection3s = list3
        };
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Collection1
{
    public int? PropId1 { get; set; }
    public int? PropId2 { get; set; }
    public int? PropId3 { get; set; }
}
public class Collection2
{
    public int? PropId1 { get; set; }
    public int? PropId2 { get; set; }
    public int? PropId3 { get; set; }
}
public class Collection3
{
    public int? PropId1 { get; set; }
    public int? PropId2 { get; set; }
    public int? PropId3 { get; set; }
}

public class ResultCollection : Collection1
{
    public ResultCollection() { }

    public ResultCollection(Collection1 collection, List<Collection2> list2, List<Collection3> list3)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in collection.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            PropertyInfo prop2 = collection.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
            if (prop2.CanWrite)
                prop2.SetValue(this, prop.GetValue(collection, null), null);
        }
        Collection2s = list2;
        Collection3s = list3;
    }

    public List<Collection2> Collection2s { get; set; }

    public List<Collection3> Collection3s { get; set; }
}
```

But can you give an example of input data?

Comment: sorry, edited the question. Can you please revisit problem statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use inheritance.

```cs
public class ResultCollection : Collection1
{
    List<Collection2> Collection2s { get; set; }
    List<Collection3> Collection3s { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```cs
var result = new ResultCollection {
    PropId1 = Collection1.PropId1,
    PropId2 = Collection1.PropId2,
    ...
    Collection2s = Collection2,
    Collection3s = Collection3
}
```

An automapper can be helpful here.
https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/

Comment: sorry, edited the question. Can you please revisit problem statement?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need to "join" collections and do new collection based on this joined lists. Look this https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.join?view=netcore-3.1